Customizing template while implementing login with Google oauth in Django
When I press the "Login with Google button", I want to go straight to the Google login screen, but I have to press the “Continue” button in the picture below to proceed. Does anyone know a way to eliminate this process...?
enter image description here
this is my code
        <div class="social-login">
            <h2>또는</h2>
            <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login with Google button</a>
        </div>

I also changed the settings.py settings as follows.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'preprint',
    'users',
    'accounts',
    # 소셜로그인
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'accounts.adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter'


